header en diferentes paginas
Quiero hacer un header que se pueda llamar desde cualquier otro archivo, pero no se como hacer con las rutas, por ejemplo en el 'a' y con la 'img'
ya que estas estan establecidas con la ruta que tiene el archivo header.js
y si yo llamo a ese archivo desde otro archivo.html no me funciona la ruta porque estoy llamando desde otro archivo
y el problema es que por ejemplo si tengo un proyecto que tiene varios archivos, no quiero poner siempre el mismo codigo del header, porque si cambio algo tengo que cambiarlo en cada archivo
por eso quiero hacerlo con un archivo.js para que pueda exportar ese header
he intentado hacer un archivo header.js, que tiene en el una funcion que me regresa un codigo html
function Header() {

    return '
        <header class="header">

            <!-- IMAGEN -->
            <img src="../imagenes/logoTienda.png" width="75px" alt="">

            <ul class="navegacion">
                <li>
                    <a href="../paginas/productos.html">PRODUCTOS</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="../paginas/sobreNosotros.html">SOBRE NOSOTROS</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="../comoTan.html">COMO TAN</a>
                </li>

                <li>
                    <a href="../miInge.html">MI INGE</a>
                </li>
            </ul>

        </header>
    ';
}


pero el problema es el es mismo, no me muestra la imagen (porque la ruta es diferente al llamar el archivo) y los  me envian a un Not Found (no se encontro la ruta)
hay alguna forma de hacerlo? no se si cambio de lenguaje a php o hago algo con las rutas, no se como resolver este problema, y en internet no hay muchas respuestas
Este es el HTML basico
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Practica header</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./componentesJs/estiloHeader.css">
</head>

<body>

     <!-- AQUI VA EL HEADER CON JS -->
    <div id="header"></div>

    <h1>INDEX</h1>

    <!-- VINCULO EL HTML CON EL JS -->
    <script src="./componentesJs/header.js"></script>

    <!-- MUSTRO EL HEADER -->
    <script>
        document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = Header()
    </script>
</body>

</html>



aclarando el header no es el head... si no un elemento html header ... tu pagina des tipo SPA ??? o cambia todo dependiendo de la ruta, no me queda clara esa parte

Diría que hay, básicamente, 3 soluciones para este problema.
Rutas absolutas
La primera es manejar rutas absolutas a los recursos, así, sin importar de dónde se llamen, siempre serán funcionales. Las rutas absolutas, en este caso, serían todas aquellas que comienzan por /, es decir, que parten de la raíz del sitio, por ejemplo:


function Header() {
  return `
    <header class="header">
      <!-- IMAGEN -->
      <img src="/imagenes/logoTienda.png" width="75px" alt="">
      <ul class="navegacion">
        <li><a href="/paginas/productos.html">PRODUCTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/paginas/sobreNosotros.html">SOBRE NOSOTROS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  `;
}

console.log(Header());



Esto funcionará independientemente de dónde se encuentre la página que lo llama en el árbol de rutas, siempre que los recursos se encuentren en la ruta absoluta referenciada.
Ruta como parámetro
La siguiente posible solución es pasar la ruta relativa como parámetro a la función header, algo como:


function Header(ruta) {
  return `
    <header class="header">
      <!-- IMAGEN -->
      <img src="` + ruta + `imagenes/logoTienda.png" width="75px" alt="">
      <ul class="navegacion">
        <li><a href="` + ruta + `paginas/productos.html">PRODUCTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="` + ruta + `paginas/sobreNosotros.html">SOBRE NOSOTROS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  `;
}


console.log(Header('../'));
console.log(Header('/'));
console.log(Header('../../recursos/'));



Detectar la ruta actual y actuar en consecuencia
Finalmente, la última opción que se me ocurre es, a partir de la URL de la página actual, formar la ruta necesaria para encontrar los recursos que buscamos.
Por ejemplo, si tu sitio usualmente está en la ruta /miSitio, y a partir de allí están las diferentes carpetas con recursos, la rutina podría lucir algo como esto:


const currentUrl = window.location.href;
//const pathname = window.location.pathname;
const pathname = '/miSitio/paginas/productos/listado/cosmeticos.html';

function Header() {
  const rutaBase = '/miSitio/';
  let ruta = '';
  if (pathname.startsWith(rutaBase)) {
    profundidad = pathname.split("/").length;
    for (let i=0; i<profundidad - 3; i++) {
      ruta = ruta + '../';
    }
  } else {
    ruta = '/miSitio/';
  }
  return `
    <header class="header">
      <!-- IMAGEN -->
      <img src="` + ruta + `imagenes/logoTienda.png" width="75px" alt="">
      <ul class="navegacion">
        <li><a href="` + ruta + `paginas/productos.html">PRODUCTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="` + ruta + `paginas/sobreNosotros.html">SOBRE NOSOTROS</a></li>
      </ul>
    </header>
  `;
}

console.log(Header());



Ojo en la definición de la constante pathname, dejé comentada la línea
const pathname = window.location.pathname;

Que es la que debieras usar en una implementación de la vida real, y dejé esta declaración solo como prueba de concepto de como funcionaría con una ruta hipotética de tu sitio.
const pathname = '/miSitio/paginas/productos/listado/cosmeticos.html';


Muchísimas gracias hermano, al final use la segunda opción, de pasarle la ruta por parámetro, muchas gracias por tu solución  <3

Puedes utilizar la etiqueta <base>, para especificar desde que ruta se comienza, en tu caso las vas variando según la carpeta donde se encuentre el HTML. Similar a la solución (2) de @jachguate, pero el parámetro iría en la <base>


<html>

<head>
  <base href="/unacaperta/" />
</head>

<body>
  <a href="./hola.html">Notar que al enlace se le ha agregado automaticamente "unacarperta" tal como indica la etiqueta base </a>
</body>

</html>



Atento que la base se escribe con un / al principio y otro al final.

Por otro lado, quizás te conviene utilizar document.write en tu script, así te ahorras hacer document.getElementById("header").innerHTML = Header(). Algo así:
header.js:
document.write(
`<header class="header">
    <img src="/imagenes/logoTienda.png" width="75px" alt="">
    <ul class="navegacion">
        <li><a href="/paginas/productos.html">PRODUCTOS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/paginas/sobreNosotros.html">SOBRE NOSOTROS</a></li>
        <li><a href="/comoTan.html">COMO TAN</a></li>
        <li> <a href="/miInge.html">MI INGE</a></li>
    </ul>
</header>`);

Y luego en tus HTML
<body>

    <!-- Se imprime el header automaticamente -->
    <script src="./componentesJs/header.js"></script>

    <h1>INDEX</h1>

</body>

